# How to get a value from List<Map<String, dynamic>> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I have set of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` data which contains the values name, amount and date.

e.g.

> [{name: Product 1, amount: 24.5, date: 2019-07-07 22:21:57}]
>
> [{name: Product 2, amount: 29.5, date: 2019-07-07 22:21:57}]

I'm passing the list into a list view builder, however before passing the list i need to validate the date in the list with the current date. Please find my code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learning_app/product.dart';

class BuildProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> products;
  final Function updateProduct;

  Tasks(this.products, this.updateProduct);

  Widget _buildCard() {
    DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();

    Widget ProductCard = Center(
      child: Text('No Products added'),
    );
    if (products.length > 0) {
      ProductCard = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: products.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if(Need to compare the date in the products == currentDate) {
            return ProductCard(products[index], index, updateProduct);
          }
        }
      );
    }
    return ProductCard;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildCard();
  }
}
```

I need to read the date value in the list and compare that with the current date before each listview item is created. Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your date with `products[index]['date']` and then compare the date with the **current date** by using any of the following:

To check if the current date is after the product's date use:
`DateTime.now().isAfter(productDate)`

OR

To check if the current date is before the product's date use:
`DateTime.now().isBefore(productDate)`.

Example:

```
DateTime productDate = DateTime.parse(products[index]['date']);
print(DateTime.now().isAfter(productDate));
print(DateTime.now().isBefore(productDate));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The map has a string as key, which in this case is `date`

```
products[index]['date']
```